# Programmatically change import URL of reference node

Tags: feeds

My question is similar to this guy's from drupal.org:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2283931

But, I have reference nodes that import content from various URLs and I want after each import, to change the (feeds source) URL of the reference node.
I guess I will use `hook_feeds_after_import()` but how am I going to target the reference node instead of the importer and run a function on that source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, it's basically the same. The `$source` object is the node itself, so in my module I called a hook like this:

```
function MYMODULE_feeds_after_import(FeedsSource $source) {

    //Get the config
    $config = $source->getConfig();

    //Save the current URL
    $url = $config['FeedsHTTPFetcher']['source'];

    //Run a basic check
    if(strstr($url, 'since')){

        //Do some fancy stuff with it and create a new one

        $newurl = 'http://foo';

        //Save the new configuration in the source node
        $config['FeedsHTTPFetcher']['source'] = $newurl;
        $source->setConfig($config);
        $source->save();
    }

}
```

Comment: In my case, I want to change the URL before the import happens so I'm using [hook_feeds_before_import()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!feeds!feeds.api.php/function/hook_feeds_before_import/7) instead.  Need to add different parameters each time.